# Use default resolver/type resolver for non-nullable field in Apollo in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, resolver, codegen

I'm using `@graphql-codegen/cli` to create a GraphQL API with Apollo. The resolvers are written in TypeScript. I cannot figure out how to use a default resolver to resolve non-nullable fields. The problem is that TypeScript seems to need me to provide values for all non-nullable fields in the main resolver, which means the default resolvers don't get used.

My GraphQL:

```
type Post {
  id: ID!
  body: String!
}
input PostsRequest {
  start: Int
  end: Int
  cursor: Int
}

type PostsResponse {
  posts: [Post!]!
  totalCount: Int!
}

extend type Query {
  posts(request: PostsRequest!): PostsResponse!
}
```

PostsResponse will never be `null`, nor will either of its fields. My resolvers are these:

```
export const PostsResolver: Resolvers<{ query: { value: number } }> = {
  Query: {
    posts: (_, { request: { start, end } }, context = { query: { value: 4 } }) => {
      const query = constructQuery(start ?? 0, end ?? 5);

      context.query = query;
      return {
        totalCount: -1,
        posts: [{ id: "-1", body: "you should never see this!" }],
      };
    },
  },
  PostsResponse: {
    posts: (_1, _2, context) => {
      const results = executeQuery(context.query);
      return results.map((result) => ({ id: result.id, body: "you should never see this!" }));
    },
    totalCount: (_1, _2, context) => executeCount(context.query),
  },
  Post: {
    body: (post) => getPostBody(post.id),
  },
};
```

This returns "you should never see this!" as all post bodies, instead of what is returned by `getPostBody()`. How can I get the default resolver to execute in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as removing the line:

```
posts: [{ id: "-1", body: "you should never see this!" }],
```

With this missing from the `posts` resolver GraphQL will go looking for it under your `PostResponse` resolver.

There you have:

```
return results.map((result) => ({ id: result.id, body: "you should never see this!" }));
```

Replace this with:

```
return results.map((result) => ({ id: result.id} ));
```

Now the resolver will *fall through* to your `Post` resolver which will return the body.